# How to set maxLength of QTableWidget item

Tags: qt, cell, qtablewidget

Is there a way to set the max length of a QTableWidget item (table cell)? I have a table that is editable and I would like the max length to be 3 when a user is editing a cell.

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of `QStyledItemDelegate` and grab the `QLineEdit` that is created for the cells. You can use `QLineEdit::setMaxLength(int)` to set the maximum length that you want.

See the [documentation of QStyledItemDelegate](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qstyleditemdelegate.html)

Comment: Hint: you should overrive createEditor method ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
tableWidget->setColumnWidth(column_number, length)
```

but 3 is small value for length, try with 30.

Comment: This is not the length of the item's content but the visual width of the column.

Comment: Length of the item's content is not mentioned in question, "table cell" is

Comment: "I would like the max length to be 3 when a user is editing a cell". Cell is synonymous to an item there, not a column.